# How do I compare different years in a D3 line chart?

Tags: svg, d3.js

I have a D3 line chart time series working well.

An example of one lines data:

```
var line1 = [
  ["2014-01-16 00:00:00",1719.2427  ],
  ["2014-01-17 00:00:00",2354.0256  ],
  ["2014-01-18 00:00:00",1940.5050  ],
  ["2014-01-19 00:00:00",2178.2483  ],
  ["2014-01-20 00:00:00",1767.8909  ],
```

This gives me a date for the X value and a point for the Y.

What I would like to do is to be able to overlay 2013 data, over the same time line.  Doing this though would extend the graph further back in time.  What I am going for is to have the 2013 data line line up with the same month and day for 2014.

Currently I am taking this date and running it throught he d3 time format function.

```
    var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
```

Any suggestions on doing a comparison like this?

Comment: using a common `d3.time.scale()` will allow you to plot multiple lines on a consistent time axis

Comment: Wouldnt that include the year though?  If I used this scale 2013 would come before 2014.

Comment: Oh OK - I misunderstood.  You can consider adding time (365 days) to the previous year's data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways of doing this. As pointed out in the comments, you could add 1 year to the parsed 2013 dates. Similarly, you could do a string replacement on the 2013 dates before parsing. If you don't care about the year though, you could ignore that when parsing:

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m-%d %H:%M:%S").parse;
parseDate(line1[0][0].substr(5));
```

Note that this will assign a year of 1900, which you may want to take into account when labelling the axis.

Comment: Should I consider switching from time to linear on the X axis?

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary as long as you don't show labels for the year.